# HTML5 Canvas Security Flaw

Tags: security

What security flaw with the HTML5 canvas is Tor Browser Bundle protecting you from when it pops up a notification about the canvas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the HTML Canvas a malicious website can perform various tests to learn a large array of information, in relation to graphics, which can be used to fingerprint users.

[Tor Project design docs (under 4.6, section 2. HTML5 Canvas Image Extraction)](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/#fingerprinting-linkability)

> After plugins and plugin-provided information, we believe that the **HTML5 Canvas** is the **single largest fingerprinting threat** browsers face today. Initial studies show that the Canvas can provide an **easy-access** fingerprinting target: The adversary simply renders WebGL, font, and named color data to a Canvas element, **extracts the image buffer**, and **computes** a hash of that **image data**. **Subtle differences** in the video card, font packs, and even font and graphics library versions allow the adversary to produce a **stable, simple, high-entropy fingerprint** of a **computer**. In fact, the hash of the **rendered image** can be used almost **identically** to a **tracking cookie** by the web server.

Also,

> To reduce the threat from this vector, we have patched Firefox to **prompt** before returning **valid image** data to the **Canvas APIs**. If the user hasn't **previously allowed** the site in the URL bar to access Canvas image data, **pure white image data** is returned to the Javascript APIs.

Basically, the HTML Canvas if allowed to be used, by either clicking not now or just using a not patched Firefox (or just another browser), allows for scary, anonymity ruining fingerprinting. On the bright side, if your accidentally allowed it, Tor Browser Bundle will [forget when you close it.](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/957/html5-canvas-image-extraction)